# sql query: To Select multiple value of second table in comma seperated form

Tags: mysql, sql

sql query to get multiple value of second table in comma seperated form. both table are joined by    tbl 1 id.

```
tbl 1
   id  category
   1    cat 1
   2    cat 2

  tbl 2
  id   tbl_1_id subcategory    
  1     1        sub 1   
  2     1        sub 2 
  3     1        sub 3
  4     2        sub 4



query result expected
1    cat 1  sub 1,sub 2,sub 3,   
2    cat 2  sub 4
```

Comment: pls. mark the DB Name.

Comment: Which DB? (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQLLite, ...)?

Comment: Working on mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mYsql you can try this (using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT function).
GROUP_CONCAT() concatenate the fields with same TABLE_1_ID and CATEGORY name - the fields listed after GROUP BY - , using a "," as a separator.

```
SELECT A.TABLE_1_ID, B.CATEGORY, GROUP_CONCAT(A.SUBCATEGORY) AS SUBC
FROM SUBCATEGORIES A
INNER JOIN CATEGORIES B
GROUP BY A.TABLE_1_ID, B.CATEGORY;
```